# Can I turn off banner ads in code?

Tags: codenameone

I set up my app to show banner ads at the bottom. Is there a way to turn off the ads in code? I want to let the users upgrade to an ad-free version of my app. But since the presences of ads is specified in the build hints, there doesn't seem to be any way to turn them off once the user buys the ad-free version. Do I need to upload two versions of the app? Will the user need to download the ad-free version once they make the purchase?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API exposure of the banner ads builtin to Codename One so there is no way to toggle them in code. You can use the [interstitial ads](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone) or use that code as the basis for creating your own banner ad support.

Comment: You didn't mention the com.codename1.components.Ads class. Is this class not used anymore?

Comment: No, it isn't used by the banner ad code. It worked with older ad providers but doesn't work with modern ad frameworks.